# Psake and robocopy failing

Tags: powershell, robocopy, psake

Robocopy will exit with a code above 0 and still possibly not be a failure. PSake detects anything above 0 as a failure and fails the build. This is fine, but how come this *still* fails:

```
task Deploy {    
        robocopy $source $dest /NP /S /XO /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS | Out-Default

    if ($lastexitcode -eq 3)
    {
       Write-Host "Got Here"
       $lastexitcode = 0       
    }

    Write-Host "Deploy local complete"
    Write-Host $lastexitcode
}

TaskTearDown {  
    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) {
        write-host "Build failed"
        exit 1
    }
}
```

I can verify that the Deploy if statement is hit and the Write-Host outputs 0, correctly, yet the TaskTearDown still detects the last exit code as 3!  How do I fix this?

Comment: I would not assign `$lastexitcode`, it's an automatic variable. Assignment perhaps creates a local variable and `TaskTearDown` still sees the original. In any case try to use a different approach without `$lastexitcode = 0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`robocopy` exit codes below 8 are non-error status codes. Only exit codes of 8 and above indicate an error. See [here](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html).

The reason why your teardown task still reports an exit code of 3 is probably because the automatic variable `$LastExitCode` is a *global* variable, whereas your deploy task creates an additional *local* variable `$lastexitcode` that masks the global variable in the scope of the task. As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943885/1630171) to a similar question, use the `$global:` prefix:

```
$global:LastExitCode = $null
```

Comment: Ah it is a scoping issue! Thanks! Still very new to posh. PSake actually looks for 0 and will throw on null ... so $global:LastExitCode = 0 is what I need.

Comment: Error code 4 (Mismatch) means that a filename exists in the source as a file, but already exists in the destination as a directory.  I would have called this an error; why is it not considered one?

Comment: @cowlinator I wouldn't know, because I wasn't involved in making that decision, and I won't speculate about the reasons.